# Why does memcached get down?

Tags: memcached

We use memcached and it hangs on each 4-5th day.
Seems like it gathers up data and faces some limitations like RAM.
And we need to restart it manually each time.

Why does it happen?
Doesnt memcached observe rest of ram?
Is it possible to set memcache up to clear the oldest data when ram is over?

Comment: It's hard to give any answer without more information about your setup. What machine are you running memcached on? Is it the only thing running? How much RAM does the machine have? Are you running it with the default slab size/growth factor/etc. settings?

Comment: it's amazon ec2 micro (~600mb), also it has running apache. Yeah all setups are default